# Does this limit exist? (Multivariable Calculus)

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sqrt{xy}}{x-y}$$

I know the function is not defined in the 2nd and 4th quadrant, nor in the line $x=y$, but I don't know if I can use a path like $x=y$ to prove the limit doesn't exist. And I had trouble finding paths in the domain that result in a limit different than $0$.

Comment: Since you suspect it doesn't converge just show that is has multiple limit points, $f(x,2x)$ and $f(x,3x)$ for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the path $y = mx$ for $m > 0$ and $m\neq 1$.

Then:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{|x|\sqrt{m}}{x(1-m)} \qquad \text{so...}$$

Comment: $|x|$ on numerator, so that you get $\operatorname{sgn}(x)\frac{\sqrt{m}}{1-m}$ it is possible that both $x,y<0$.

Comment: @zwim Oh, you're right. Going to edit.